Black and white suspense movie
I'm looking for an old Hollywood black and white movie, probably from the 1940's or 50's, very suspenseful. Famous actors but I can't remember who.
The plot is centred around a man and a woman. She is innocent and he gains her trust throughout the movie though he is supected of a murder I think. We believe that it wasn't him but the last scene shows him talking to her at the gate of a house (at least that's the image I have) and suddenly she realizes that he's guilty because she sees the object that proves his guilt. Is it a glove or a ring or something, whatever I can't remember!
I thought it was a Hitchcock but I've been through most of them and can't find it.
It's definitely set in the 40's or maybe early 50's, in the city but I can't say if it's in England or the USA. The men are wearing suits and hats typical of the period, there's something about what he says or does or has at the end that makes her realize "Oh my God it's him."

When and where was the movie set .... was it contemporary 40's or 50's USA?

More details would be good, but it might be Suspicion. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034248

At a stretch this could also be Rebecca .... the gates of Mandeley are highlighted in the movie, and partially it is about the guilt / innocence of the husband in the movie.  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032976/

Actually, the first thing that came to my mind was the ring in Shadow of a Doubt...

Thanks for your replies! It's not Suspicion because she discovers that he's a good guy at the end so it's the other way round. Not Rebecca either or Shadow of a Doubt (though I admit the plot is totally similar) because that one ends in a train.Maybe that's why I thought of the ring.) It's definitely set in the 40's or maybe early 50's, in the city but I can't say if it's in England or the USA. The men are wearing suits and hats typical of the period, there's something about what he says or does or has at the end that makes her realize "Oh my God it's him."

Feel free to [edit] any additional information into the question.

The Hitchcock movie that comes closest to this is Shadow of a Doubt. The bad guy murders and robs rich women. In particular he wears a ring he stole. To get away and lie low he visits his loving sister's family across the country; his niece thinks the world of him. No one suspects anything about anything. The murder(s) happen in New York(?) and the bulk of the movie is in an idyllic small town in California.
The ring has an inscription with unfamiliar names; this is when Charlie (the niece) begins to wonder about her uncle.
The climax is on a moving train when the niece realizes the truth. Suddenly-not-so-loving uncle Charlie tries to kill her by throwing her off the train.
Gaslight. Here, the husband was looking for some jewels up in the house attic. Only as he is caught does he discover it was right in front of him all the time, sewn into a jeweled dress. The house is in London.
Ingrid Bergman was in Gaslight but not Shadow of a Doubt. Charles Boyer was her no-good husband.
Joseph Cotten was in both.
Teresa Wright was the niece in Shadow of a Doubt.

OP had said in comments that it's neither, though.
